# Ошибка при установке модуля для Python

Tags: python, pip, numba

Пытался установить numba командой pip install numba, но вылезла ошибка, хотя python установлен. Что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть 2 варианта.
Либо твой путь (Path) не работает попробоуй переустановить Path
Либо данный модуль не совместим версии Python. Попробуй установить разные версии Питон пакета.Удачи

Comment: Я уже 2 раза переустановил python, может эта проблема из за того, что у меня русские символы в абсолютном пути?

Comment: @KirillShibalenkov так и есть, скорее всего

Comment: Я переустановил python на диск d, теперь в абсолютном пути нет русских символов, но ошибка остается. Все равно вылезает ошибка     FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
    error: command 'd:\\python3\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1